# Best approach for storing session in load balancer

Tags: php, session, redis, load-balancing

I would like to ask your advise about how to manage sessions for 3 server instances used by the load balancer.

Currently, we have a new architecture of our new servers. The admin server has 3 instances to handle requests. All admin servers has the same source codes. Unlike before, we don't use load balancer so there wasn't an issue with session logging out so easily. Right now, we implement the load balancer, thus there was an issue with the session logging out whenever I clicked other links in the admin site.

The admin application uses Zend 2 framework. We liked to implement Redis to store the session. Is this a better approach? If so, do we have to install Redis in each admin server instances? How would the session be managed through Redis if there would be 3 server instances?

I'm sorry. This is new to me. Correct me if I misinterpreted it. I highly appreciate any ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: "do we have to install Redis in each admin server instances" - no, have just one redis, outside of app servers, and configure all app servers to use it.

Comment: Okay, so if I have a db server and it has Redis running, then the app servers can use it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.